# confusing answers to a multiple choice question in probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

While prepping for my probability exam i have come across the following multiple choice question:

We perform a series of Bernoulli experiments with parameters p,q until we achieve r successes.
let r be positive integer constant  that is determine beforehand.
let X be a random variable of the number of experiments (until r successes).
then, E(X/r):

1. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{q}{p})^k + (\frac{-q}{p})^r r*ln(p) $$
2. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{p}{q})^k + (\frac{-q}{p})^r r*ln(p) $$
3. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{p}{q})^k + (\frac{-p}{q})^r r*ln(p) $$
4. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{q}{p})^k + (\frac{-p}{q})^r r*ln(p) $$
5. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{p}{q})^k + (\frac{p}{q})^r r*ln(p) $$
6. $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} (-1)^{k-1} (\frac{r}{r-k}) (\frac{q}{p})^k + (\frac{q}{p})^r r*ln(p) $$
7. there are no correct answers.

at first my instinct was to just say it should be 1/p as it looks like the negative binomial distribution and using the linearity of exception it should be the answer. but, according to my professor, the answer is actually the third option! he did not share with me the way he got to the solution but gave the clue to prove that E(X/r) should equal to:
$$ -r\sum_{k=r}^{\infty} k^{-1}[\frac{(k-1)!}{((r-1)!(k-r)!)}]p^r(1-p)^{k-r} $$

can someone explain how to get to answer 3 and (maybe even more importantly) why is it not just the negative binomial distribution?

Comment: Faced with the question without the answers, I too would have said $E[X]=\frac{r}{p}$ and so $E\left[\frac Xr\right]=\frac1p$

Comment: Are you sure the question is not about $E(r/X)$?

Comment: maybe that is what he meant but the question states E(X/r). i thought he might have meant conditional, but in terms of the actual question it states E(X/r).

Comment: I guess, and it is just a guess, that what was meant was $\frac rX$.Just reverse engineering the hint.  The probability that it takes exactly $k$ trials, for $k≥r$, is $P_k=\binom {k-1}{r-1}p^rq^{k-r}$ so the expected value of $\frac rX$ is $\sum_{k=r}^{\infty} \frac rk P_k$ which matches the hint up to sign.  No guess on where the sign comes from.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555870/321264

Comment: ha it looks like that might be it. i do wonder if there are cases when E(r/X) is actually the same as E(X/r) and that it why that is the question, but it just might be that he had a typo. anyways, thanks a lot!!!